# How to turn off authentication for websockets in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security, websocket

I've got a Java EE application which uses Spring Security for authentication (configured with Java config). The same application contains a websocket server implemented with `javax.websocket` package.

My question is how to turn off Spring Security authentication for any incoming websocket connections without turning off HTTP authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have all requests matching a particular pattern bypass the security filter. For example, if your WS endpoint is
`/websocket` you can add this to your configuration:

```
<http pattern="/websocket/**" security="none" />
```

I don't like to configure Spring programmatically so I don't know how this is done with Java code, but after a 10,000 feet look at the 
classes I think it's maybe done with a [WebSecurity](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/WebSecurity.html) + [WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#configure%28org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity%29) setup.